Move GB files from one prefix to another in S3 using Lambda
I weekly run a lambda function triggered by an Eventbridge rule to move files from a S3 prefix (landing) to a different prefix in the same bucket (hist). The lambda has a timeout of 5 minutes.
It works as expected for small files, but when it comes to objects of 2-3 GB, the lambda takes already 5 minutes to copy and delete each file. Throwing a timeout exception.
Do you know what would be the correct way of handling this? I am thinking of increasing the lambda memory until finding the optimal.
Here is the code and a screenshot of the logs for a better idea.
What I ended up doing: using a queue from my point of view would unnecessary add costs considering how simple is my use case. The lambda constantly moves 7 files each week, files of 2-3 GB. The main problem here were the awaits on SDK copy command. There's nothing that can be done with how much time the CLI commands take to complete, but with the use of JavaScript Promise chains I could copy all files asynchronously and execute the delete after their finishing, all in the same lambda. For files larger than 5 GB I recommend using multipart upload.
TIA


export async function handler() {

    console.log("Moving objects from ", sourcePrefix, " to ", destinationPrefix)

    var today = new Date();
    var daysSinceSunday = today.getDay(); // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ...

    // Sunday from 2 weeks ago
    var twoSundaysAgo = new Date(today)
    twoSundaysAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - daysSinceSunday - 7);
    twoSundaysAgo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)

    let messageText = `:bucket: *Historical Data Archiver ${twoSundaysAgo.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}* \n` +
    `*Bucket:* \`${bucketName}\`\n` +
    `*S3 Prefix Source:* \`${sourcePrefix}\`\n` +
    `*S3 Prefix Destination:* \`${destinationPrefix}\`\n`

    const webhookUrl = await getSecretValue(secretNameWebhook, keyNameWebhook)

    try {

        const listObjectsCommand = new ListObjectsCommand({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Prefix: sourcePrefix,
        })

        const listedObjects = await s3.send(listObjectsCommand)

        if (!listedObjects.Contents) {
            console.log('0 objects eligible for archival')
            messageText += `:eight_spoked_asterisk: *Status*: 0 objects eligible for archival\n`
        } else {
            let numObjects = 0
            //Loop objects
            for (const object of listedObjects.Contents) {
                const objectDate = new Date(object.LastModified)
                //Remove objects from two Sundays ago and before
                if (objectDate <= twoSundaysAgo) {
                    const copyCommand = new CopyObjectCommand({
                        Bucket: bucketName,
                        CopySource: `${bucketName}/${object.Key}`,
                        Key: object.Key.replace(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix),
                    })
                    //copy to hist path
                    await s3.send(copyCommand)

                    const deleteCommand = new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: object.Key })
                    //delete from origin path
                    await s3.send(deleteCommand)

                    console.log('Successfully moved object:', object.Key)

                    numObjects += 1
                }
            }

            //0 objects were moved
            if(numObjects == 0){
                messageText += `:eight_spoked_asterisk: *Status*: 0 objects eligible for archival\n`
            }else{
                messageText += `:white_check_mark: *Status*: Successfully moved \`${numObjects}\` objects.\n`
            }
        }
        //Everything went smoothly, send message to slack
        const fallbackMessage = `New transition objects from landing to hist S3`
        await sendTextToSlackBasic(messageText, fallbackMessage, green, webhookUrl)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error moving objects: ${error}`)
        messageText += `:x: *Error*: \`${error.message}\`\n`
        const fallbackMessage = `Error hist S3: ${error.message}`
        await sendTextToSlackBasic(messageText, fallbackMessage, red, webhookUrl)
        throw error
    }
}





It's not going to to show a timeout exception - Lambda will just terminate your code with no warning. You can see in the Lambda console that there were errors when executing.
Either increase the timeout, or better yet, use a different architecture - e.g. send the list of keys to SQS, and then use a SQS subscription to move the files in batches.

I agree with @gshpychka -- instead of copying multiple objects per Lambda invocation, just copy a single object. Have one Lambda function that grabs a list of objects to move, then send them as messages (one object per message) to an Amazon SQS queue and then configure the "copy" Lambda function to trigger off the SQS queue. The Lambda functions will run in parallel and they will be processed in less time.

Assuming the number of files can increase indefinitely over time, you will be hitting new memory and timeout limits no matter of the increase of the latter. It is indeed a good idea to redesign the functionality to include sqs queue that can spawn lambdas per each file accommodating to your actual workloads.

Also note that this code can only copy objects of up to 5gb.  If your data will ever grow beyond that, you'll need to create a multipart upload and use uploadPartCopy.

But even with a queue, each object will take 5 minutes. Imagine objects are 15 GB instead of 2.5, then the lambda will surpass the 15 minutes. Even increasing memory, what is consuming time is the copy command delegated to SDK. Is there no better way of doing this?

The code was inefficient waiting for the copy command to complete. Applying javascript chains speeded up the lambda drastically.
